# I want to show actual price of product with discount price at invoice pdf

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

Product Cheap special price is 9988, and it's actual price was 9999. i want to show **actual price 9999** and **discount price 9988** in the invoice. please help me. thank you.

[image]

Comment: For add the actual price you need to add the special price variable in the file, where your pdf generation file is.

Comment: File that is printing the prices of products on pdf has $item veriable. And i am unable to get special price/ actual price of product from $item. @NitinPawar

Comment: You need to query and get it from the database table where product actual price is stored.

Comment: Alright. THANK YOU @NitinPawar. can you please tell me table name or any thing else, that might help me do it more fast please.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `$_item->getProduct()->getPrice()` to get the original price.

```
 <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getProduct()-‌​>getPrice()) ?>
```

Comment: Tried that one. But it come with "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getProduct() on null".

Comment: Are you paying any attention to what you copy? Or the errors that you get? This answer said `$_item`, the other other said `$item` if $_item is null, it won't have a member function called getProduct().  If you're using the link from 153099 to add it as an attribute you probably want to look into adding it into the sales_flat_order_item first, as the price attribute could change between the order being created and the invoice being created

Answer (score 0):

You should lookup in app/design/frontend/(theme_name)/default/template/email/orde‌​r/items/invoice/defa‌​ult.phtml There should be a section with item price - it varies depending of template you use. There you are able to put the code to display regular price.

```
getOriginalPrice()
getPrice()
getDiscountAmount
```

Comment: But sir i want to get original price in app/code/local/sales/model/order/pdf/item/invoice/default.php. kindly tell me what to do?

Comment: So for that I think you need to try this :`$item->getPrice()),` in app/code/local/sales/model/order/pdf/item/invoice/default.ph‌​p

Comment: I have already tried this one. This shows me the final price. That is 9988, and i want to get 9999.

Comment: ok finally Try This one : ` $orderItem->getBasePriceInclTax();`

Comment: Same result sir. Again showing 9988. Now what?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getProduct()->getData('price')); ?>
```